# How do I run a command with spaces in a github workflow

Tags: windows, yaml, github-actions

I need to install an extension for Visual Studio Code in a [github workflow](https://docs.github.com/en/actions). I want to run this command in the workflow:

```
run: C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/code.exe --install-extension ms-dynamics-smb.al
```

However, the github runner does not like this:

```
Run C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\code.exe --install-extension ms-dynamics-smb.al
C:\Program: D:\a\_temp\e14dee42-ae33-48ac-ad4e-44f4e4600de5.ps1:2
Line |
   2 |  C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\code.exe --install-extension ms-dy …
     |  ~~~~~~~~~~
     | The term 'C:\Program' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable
     | program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct
     | and try again.
```

I tried the following variations, but everything fails:

```
run "C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\code.exe --install-extension ms-dynamics-smb.al"
--> Invalid workflow file

run "C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/code.exe --install-extension ms-dynamics-smb.al"
--> The term 'C:/Program' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet...

run 'C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/code.exe --install-extension ms-dynamics-smb.al'
--> The term 'C:/Program' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet...

run \"C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/code.exe\" --install-extension ms-dynamics-smb.al
--> The term '\C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/code.exe\' is not recognized...
```

How do I properly handle/escape a path with spaces in a github workflow file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
run: |
  & "C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/code.exe" --install-extension ms-dynamics-smb.al
```

so you use a YAML block instead of quoting words?

Comment: Thanks, @AKX, your solution almost worked out of the box, I just had to quote the entire command including arguments.

Comment: I was a bit hasty here. What you proposed does not throw an error but the command is not executed for some reason. The extension is not installed. I updated my question accordingly.

Comment: Well, what if you sidestep the problem and add `working-directory: "C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/"` and run `code.exe`?

Comment: thank you! I spent too much time trying to figure this one out.

Comment: @binford I edited the answer to add your latest suggestion

Answer (score 0):

What AKX proposed is close to what worked out in the end. I had three errors in my build.yaml

- I called the wrong command. If you want to do command line stuff with Visual Studio Code you need to call `C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/bin/code.cmd`
- You need to use quotes around the command if the path contains spaces
- If you use quotes in powershell, you have to prefix your command with `&`. Otherwise powershell just interprets it as a string and returns the string.

This is the solution:

```
run: |
  & "C:/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/bin/code.cmd" --install-extension ms-dynamics-smb.al
```

I wanted to post this as an edit on AKX's answer, but the SO reviewers rejected my edit and suggested posting it as a separate answer. I am keeping AKX's answer as accepted answer as he put me on the right track.